# Como cargar diferentes perfiles en una misma pagina?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un sitio(o estoy haciendolo)en el que puedo ver el perfil del usuario que yo seleccione desde el **index.html**.

Esta pagina donde se cargan los datos del usuario se llama **user.php** y la pagina donde veo el perfil del usuario actual(logueado)se llama **perfil.php**.

Esa idea me la dieron hace mucho de que tiene que haber dos paginas,las antes mencionadas.

Bien,estuve viendo el funcionamiento de este sitio,el de twitter,facebook,etc y me di cuenta que lo unico que cambia es el id o el nombre de usuario cuando me traslado de uno a otra.

me explico:

Cuando visitas tu perfil en facebook en la url tienes:

```
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100010542947857(este es el mio),
```

Por el simple hecho de cambiar un numero de eso,me lleva a otro perfil,pero sigue siendo la misma pagina,osea,**profile.php**.Y que es lo que cambia?la estructura ni el diseño cambian,lo único que cambian son los botones,en el perfil del usuario logueado te salen,actualizar información,ver registro de actividad,y si vas a otro perfil te salen los botones mensaje,enviar solicitud,etc.

por ejemplo:

```
http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/12878/luis

ese es la dirección de mi perfil.
```

---

pero si hay un usuario llamado jose2000 y quiero ir a su perfil solo tengo que borrar "luis"(del final de la dirección de mas arriba) y poner "jose2000".

Entonces mi duda es,acaso no se puede hacer eso con una solo pagina,por ejemplo "perfil.php" y que cuando entre al perfil del usuario logueado me cargue no solo sus datos sino tambien los botones de configuracion,modificar perfil,etc.

No se si entienden.

Comment: me parece que lo que buscas es un json o nodejs para actualizar en tiempo real los estados, o bien puedes crear tu sitio y dependiendo el usuario que inicie, este sitio tome los datos de una bd para ponerlos en su interface.

Comment: "o bien puedes crear tu sitio y dependiendo el usuario que inicie, este sitio tome los datos de una bd para ponerlos en su interface""  ESo  lo tengo implementado

Comment: Pero,una pregunta, se requiere de una o dos paginas para visualizar los datos del usuario logueado y los de los usuarios que yo visite sus perfiles???Esa es mi duda,porque entonces pasaria a formular otra pregunta diferente.

Comment: @luis puedes programar si tu quieres todo en una sola pagina, yo lo he hecho, a mi parecer no es difícil, pero necesitaras manejar otro tipo de sistemas, ya sea ajax entre otros, ahora con lo que dices del usuario puedes hacer algo como `$_GET['user'];` y en la url sería algo como: `perfil.php?user=xxxx` .

Comment: Podrias poner algo de codigo, que es lo que estas realizando, me imagino que cuando el usuario inicia sesión, tendra una sesión con su identificador. Simplemente con eso ya podrias crear el sistema que estas poniendo en tu ejemplo.

Comment: @D.Bulten eso es mucho codigo,serias mas especifico?ya que cada pagina,tanto perfil.php como user.php sobrepasan las 900 lineas.

Comment: @nikomaster ESa es la forma que utilizo para hacerlo,pero recojo los datos del usuario que visito su perfil en user.php y quiero hacerlo en perfil.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo sin problemas con una sola página, lo único que necesitas es comprobar que el usuario identificado es el mismo que el que se está mostrando en perfil.php.

Como no has mostrado código no puedo darte una respuesta apropiada para tu caso, pero te indico como podrías hacerlo.

Supongamos que en tu página tienes el objeto usuario para almacenar los datos de sesión actuales, y que la página perfil dispone del parámetro  id (como el ejemplo que has puesto de facebook).

Lo único que necesitas, es un condicional que englobe los botones, enlaces o contenido personal solo para el usuario logueado, lo haces de esta manera:

```
<?php if ($usuario && ($usuario->getId() == $_GET['id'])) { ?>
    ... Botones, enlaces o contenido a mostrar cuando se trata de tu propio perfil ...
<?php }?>
```

Deberás adaptar el condicional a tu sistema de usuarios pero yo creo que la idea queda clara.

Comment: Si, tengo el id del usuario logueado en una variable llamada $my_id.Ah,y a la hora de mostrar los botones,¿como lo hago?los imprimo con echo o hay algo mas.?

Comment: Ademas  no utilizo POO

Comment: @luis entonces tendrías que cambiar  ($usuario && ($usuario->getId() == $_GET['id'])) por ($my_id == $_GET['id'])), tal y como te lo he puesto en el ejemplo los botones, enlaces y contenido propio puede ir en HTML normal como el resto de la página

Comment: Entonces en la codicion,si el usuario es el mio(logueado)imprimere con un echo los botones modificar,claro el HTML,y si es el perfil del usuario visitado imprimire algo como un boton que diga enviar mensaje.Esta bien asi??

Comment: @luis No es necesario que los imprimas con un echo, de hecho imprimir código HTML mediante PHP es una técnica poco aconsejada, simplemente incluye el código HTML crudo (tál cual sin adicciones PHP) entre la condición que te he puesto en el ejemplo (en otras palabras, sustituyes la linea que empieza por ... por el HTML), si necesitas obtener datos dinámicos para el HTML incluido utiliza el echo sólo para ese dato, no para el código HTML completo

Comment: Ahora que veo mas detenidamente tu ejemplo,veo algo que nunca he hecho.Abriste la primera llave y pusiste la etiqueta de cerrado de php..Entonces como pregunta cada vez que yo tenga que poner algo (boton)debo envolverlo con un codigo asi?

Comment: @luis Supongo que normalmente imprimes todo el código HTML con PHP e.g: <?php echo('<a href="' . $url . '">Enlace</a>') ?>, es recomendable por temas de rendimiento utilizar PHP sólo cuando es estrictamente necesario, en este caso sólo lo necesitamos para $url y lo haremos de esta manera: <a href="<?php echo($url)?>">Enlace</a>, otro consejo más, si tu PHP tiene habilitado el uso de short tags puedes ahorrarte el echo de esta forma: <?=$url?>

Comment: Lo voy a  hacer con tu ejemplo y por cada botón que yo baya a poner le pondré envuelto con el código que me diste.Ya la probé y funciona bien.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno si se trata de reescribir la vista en términos de MVC , ahora sobre editar usuarios hay dos casos:

1. Editar los datos de cualquier usuario que visites como un modo
   administrador
2. Solo el usuario autenticado pueda modificar sus datos.

Como verás es necesario manejar roles por usuario , de esta forma lo que un administrador puede hacer se le restringe a un usuario de menor nivel

Te dejo un ejemplo básico de cómo implementarlo, recuerda que el el identificador de usuario  es el que ocuparas para cargar los datos debes extraer datos y cargarlos en tu vista (user.php) por medio de POST O GET ,

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/9582c9/script-for-login-logout-and-view-using-php-mysql-and-boots/

Lets go!

Comment: Necesito el punto 2.En el que cada usuario modifica su perfil.

Comment: Pero,una pregunta, se requiere de una o dos paginas para visualizar los datos del usuario logueado y los de los usuarios que yo visite sus perfiles???Esa es mi duda

Comment: Claro solo que al cargar los datos debes comparar (id usuario logueado ==  usuario visita ?)   .. si son iguales habilitas los botones (funciones para editar datos) , de lo contrario los bloqueas  por jQuery o php al mandarlos como respuesta en HTML

Comment: Con variables $_SESSION te aseguras de la permanencia de tus credenciales al loguearte hay otras técnicas como local storage